# Ruby on Rails : Updating Multiple Models from single view/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Ruby 1.8.6 & Rails 1.2.

Models: `Job`, `JobExtraStop`:

```
class JobExtraStop < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :job 
end 

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :lead, :foreign_key => :id 
  has_one :quote, :foreign_key => :id 
  has_many :credit_card 
  has_many :job_extra_stops 
end
```

Code from View:

Main View

```
<%= render_partial 'jobs/job_address_stop_fields', "stop" => stop, "index"=> index %>
```

Partial that is called:

```
 <span class="jasf" id="lead_form_adrr_fields">

 <% fields_for "job_extra_stop[#{index}]", stop do |extra_stop_form| %>
<tr>
         <td><%= extra_stop_form.text_field :st_num, :size => 2%></td>
          <td><%= extra_stop_form.text_field :st_name,  :size => 15%></td>
          <td><%= extra_stop_form.text_field :apt_num,  :size => 2%></td>
          <td><%= extra_stop_form.text_field :city,  :size => 9%></td>
          <td><%= extra_stop_form.text_field :zip,  :size => 5%></td>
          <td><%= extra_stop_form.select(:state,( [[ "Select State", "" ]] + State::NAMES)) %>

          </td>
          <td><%= extra_stop_form.text_field :floor,  :size => 2%></td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= extra_stop_form.text_field :elevator, :size => 1%></td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= extra_stop_form.text_field :action_type,  :size => 5%></td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= extra_stop_form.select(:location_type, ([["pick-up"],["drop-off"],["extra_stop"]] )) %></td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= extra_stop_form.text_field :note,  :size => 10%></td>
          <td>^ / v</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to_function "Remove", "$(this).up('.jasf').remove()" %></td>
</tr> 
<% end %> 
</span>
```

Error:

> Undefined Local Variable or method index

Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It would be worth your effort to update to Rails 3.

Comment: Thanks! Its not an option at this given moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct syntax for passing local variables to your partial, check here for the correct syntax http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Comment: I have a new issue, I have updated the code and the new error